# Calculating Gas of A Uniswap Exchange With Web3js

Tags: web3js, javascript, uniswap, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I am trying to calculate the gas that a contract will use prior to executing it. I realize that it is not possible to get a 100% exact value but I would still like to calculate an estimate. I am new to using web3 and have not been able to get a gas estimate when working with the Uniswap SDK. I have found a few descriptions online but they were all either outdated or I was unable to get them to work. How do I go about estimating the gas that will be required to run a swapExactETHForTokens()? I have managed to make a program that can properly perform the swap however I would like to know roughly how much gas is required before running it. I have seen some people use things like .deploy() but I have not been able to find the proper ABI and Bytecode to be used. If .deploy().estimateGas() is the best method for performing this, what would be the inputs when using the uniswap sdk? I am very new to all this so a simpler explanation is best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code did you try? and how it failed to estimate the gas required?

Comment: I don't have the exact code since once it didn't work I would delete it. I would call the function using MyContract.swapExactETHForTokens(Params) and from there I tried different variations where I would go MyContract.deploy(ABI).estimateGas() or other combinations including the uniswap method etc. I would find the ABI by taking the contract uniswap address (0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D) and putting it into etherscan then copying and pasting the section called "Contract ABI". I am also unsure what inputs estimateGas would require or if that is even the best way of going about it.

Comment: Check the web3 documentation about gas estimation https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas. You won't need to call deploy since it is for deploying a new contract.